# Trying to identify a plant with pain-killing properties from northern Vietnam

Tags: species-identification, botany

My mother-in-law uses this plant to alleviate her pain caused by a severe case of spondylitis. This is a plant used in traditional medicine in her village near Hanoi, Vietnam. She doesn't know the name of the plant, even in Vietnamese. I'm interested in identifying this plant mainly to find out its exact pharmacological properties (if any) and possible side-effects.

This is a climbing plant that can easily become as tall as a big tree. It is present year-round in this region.

To use it she just cuts it longitudinally and let it dry in the sun before boiling it and drinking the resulting decoction.

Here is a picture that she took of the plant in the wild. This is the one with the heart-shaped leaves.

[image: The plant in the wild]

And here is another picture where she removed the leaves from the plant.

[image: The same plant with leaves removed]

Comment: Is the plant she uses the one with the heart-shaped leaves?  There are several plants in that picture near the vine stem, just want to make sure we are looking at the right plant.

Comment: Yes, the plant with the heart-shaped leaves is the one she uses. Sorry for the ambiguity. I have edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: it might be this plant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telosma_cordata it looks like some of the uses fit your description.